# Is it possible to get 100% game completed without going multiplayer in Burnout Legends?

Tags: burnout-legends

Basically, is it possible to obtain 100% game completion in Burnout Legends in single-player only? I completed all the World Tour events, around 1/3 of the Crash events, most of both World Tour and Crash finished with Gold medals. However, I am currently at around 55% of game completed. I noticed that obtaining Gold medals in events does not increase my %, only unlock Legend GPs in World Tour.

It seems without playing multi I will not get all the cars, since Collector cars can be only unlocked by challenging other players. There are 5 collectors per tier, one is won through World Tour event, thus resulting in 20 cars I probably won't have. On the other hand - do unlocked cars count towards % of game completion anyway?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's](http://www.gamespot.com/burnout-legends/cheats/platform/psp) how to unlock all cars. Car models may differ from each UMD disk.

You must unlock each vehicle to get 100%.